# C library for images

Tags: open-source, library, images, c

Is there a library for reading/writing images that supports common raster graphics formats like JPG, PNG, and BMP? I want it to decode common sound formats into a simple stream loaded into memory.

Sure, I can use [ImageMagick MagickCore](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php), but I do not need all of its functionality. The alternative is to use [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) and [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and wrapper functions to choose decoder, but it would be nice if there already is a "multiformat" library.